# Grid Layout on Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout, grid

I'm looking to create a grid layout - a complicated version actually. Since I am new at Java (I have created some Android Applications) I don't really know how to do this.

Let me explain: I want a grid layout, that looks like this:

[image: Desired grid layout]

But, instead of having pictures and colours inside of each box of the grid.. I want to have a box with 3 apps that the user can change. Kind of like the bottom part of Aviate launcher.

Like this:

[image: Desired box content]

So basically, I would like to have a grid layout, that the user can resize each part of the grid, each grid have a 3 apps inside, and the user can redefine those apps.

So how can I do something like that?

Thanks in advance if you understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand clearly. But, if you are looking for Gridlayout, try http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html
Or, if you want to make a widget try open source project like https://github.com/twotoasters/HorizontalImageScroller-Android

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I am trying to implement Image #2 into every box of Image #1, Like every box of the grid has 3 apps inside of it, and the user can change the apps inside every box and resize each box. I know it's a lot to ask though.

Comment: NOrmally we used to add ImageView to the Adapter. Instead, if you create a ViewGroup which can hold 3 ImageViews & add that as individual item to the adapter, it can solve your problem right